# Запятая при однородных, неоднородных определениях 4

Tags: пунктуация

Труппа отразилась вверх ногами, в смешном(,) изогнутом и растянутом виде.

Нужна ли указанная запятая? По правилу, если за прилагательным следует одиночное причастие запятая не ставится. Ср.:  **(гладко причесанные черные волосы).** Но у Куприна запятая стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Нужна.

> Определения однородны, если характеризуют предмет с разных сторон, но в данном контексте объединяются каким-то общим признаком;
>
> Лунный, ясный вечер – «лунный, а потому и ясный»; тяжёлые, мрачные времена – «тяжёлые, а потому и мрачные».

https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/713-232_odnorodnye_i_neodnorodnye_opredeleniya.html